# python2.7.6 UnboundLocalError in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey I am working on a python game for class and I have struck this error that has been bugging me for days now. The part of the code I am having trouble with is below. Also I can't figure out how to make all of the letters stay in the list. What do I need to fix so this can run the way I need it to?

```
def update (blanks, letter, word):
if letter in word:
    for i in range (len(blists)):
        if letter == word[i]:
            blists[i] = word[i]
            bstring = ''.join(blists)
return bstring

word = 'tomato'
letter = raw_input ('Please guess a letter. ')

blanks = '_' * len(word)
blists = list(blanks)
bstring = ''.join(blists)
wrong = ''
correct = ''

while True:
    blanks = '_' * len(word)
    blists = list(blanks)
    bstring = ''.join(blists)
    blanks_str = ''.join(blists)
    letter = raw_input ('Please guess a letter. ')
    i = update (blanks, letter, word) 
    print i
```

EDIT:
The Error i am getting is an UnboundLocalError. This occurs when the while loop starts the update function and the bstring is the error. It also doesn't do what I want it to do. I want it to display the words on the string, whether correct or incorrect. I want it to be similar to the hangman game output from http://inventwithpython.com/chapter9.html

Comment: So what's the problem? You getting an error message? Tell us the message. It doesn't do what you want? What do you want? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

The error message it gives is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hangman.py", line 24, in <module>
    i = update (blanks, letter, word) 
  File "hangman.py", line 7, in update
    return bstring
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bstring' referenced before assignment
```

Note the source of the problem (line 7) and indicating "local variable 'bstring' referenced before assignment"

I think you need to declare bstring as a global in the function update, i.e. add this line to the beginning of your

```
global bstring
```

If I remember correctly, the fact that you may assign to it means that it will create it as a local variable, unless you explicitly declare it global.  When you return it, if you haven't assigned it, it sees an unassigned local variable, hence the error.

At least I think that's what's going on.  It worked for me when I added the global declaration.